# how to calculate Time Difference in AM PM format

Tags: javascript, web

I am using jsp page and i want to calculate time diff in start time to end time and shoe to total time input which is readOnly="true"
function TSTimediff(counter) {

```
var start = document.getElementById("activitylogFrom"+counter).value;
var end =   document.getElementById("activitylogTo"+counter).value;
if(start > end){
    alert("From Time Must Be less than To Time");
    console.log(start+":"+end)
}
else if(end > start){
    start.split(':');
    end.split(':');
    var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
    var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
    var total = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    console.log(total)

    var hours = Math.floor(total / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    total -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(total / 1000 / 60);
    return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
    }
    
    total = document.getElementById("activitylogTotalTime");
    
 }
*emphasized text*
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you have two input fields with type="time". Here is an approach to get the difference of times on the same day.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  document.getElementById("diff").addEventListener("click", function () {
    const startVal = document.getElementById("activitylogFrom").value;
    const start = startVal.split(":");
    const endVal = document.getElementById("activitylogTo").value;
    const end = endVal.split(":");

    const startTime = new Date();
    startTime.setHours(start[0]);
    startTime.setMinutes(start[1]);

    const endTime = new Date();
    endTime.setHours(end[0]);
    endTime.setMinutes(end[1]);

    if (startTime > endTime) {
      alert("From Time Must Be less than To Time");
      console.log(startVal + " - " + endVal);
    } else {
      let diffInMinutes = (endTime - startTime) / 1000 / 60;
      const hours = Math.floor(diffInMinutes / 60);
      const minutes = diffInMinutes % 60;
      const total =
        (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") +
        hours +
        ":" +
        (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") +
        minutes;

       document.getElementById("activitylogTotalTime").innerHTML = total;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <label for="activitylogFrom">Start</label>
    <input type="time" id="activitylogFrom" />

    <label for="activitylogTo">End<label>
    <input type="time" id="activitylogTo" />

    <div>
      Total time: <span id="activitylogTotalTime"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="diff">diff</button>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```